# Pathlib crashes on Unicode-Symbol iff program is packaged with PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, pyinstaller, pathlib

My python-program creates a lockfile:

```
output_file_path = Path(output_folder_path, filename)

Path(output_file_path.as_posix() + ".lock").touch()
```

Note, that the filename contains german-unicode-characters.
If I execute this in PyCharm, everything works just fine.

However, if and only if I create an executable with:

```
 python3 -m PyInstaller --onefile main.py
```

Then on execution this will raise a:

```
File "pathlib.py", line 1295, in touch
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 57: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is either an issue with my code, pathlib, pyinstaller or the way I'm combining them.

EDIT: I have been asked to provide a minimal reproducible example:

```
from pathlib import Path
Path("/tmp/", "This should be a valid file: üöä").touch()
```

The upper statement works in PyCharm, but raises an exception in a packaged program.

How do I fix this?

(I'd prefer to do this "properly" and not just simply delete all unicode chars.)

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Manjaro-Linux. The script is executed by systemd.

Comment: What is the `locale` of the user executing the script in systemd?

Comment: `en_DE.UTF-8` (systemd runs it in --user mode)

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ I was able to find a oneliner that reproduces the issue.